# DocusignGroup Administrator

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to create a group admin using the API?

Someone who is able to add and delete users from the group but not from the general administrator account?

I can see there are only 3 permissions profile that can be assigned to a group, Administrator

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently DocuSign does not use a tiered administrator structure with either the API or their standard console.

Several DocuSign employee's that I've talked with have suggested that a tiered structure is in the works but they don't have a release date for that as yet.

As a temporary fix to this, if you have an account administrator at DocuSign (and depending upon your account set up) you can request that they create sub-accounts to which you can assign groups of users and limit administrators from reaching other accounts. This is the solution we used for multiple business units that didn't need access to each others documents.

You can create more permissions profiles, but the degree to which your users can access settings remains largely the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply, all the subaccounts have to be of admin type if they want to delete and add users to their groups but since they would be admin, it would mean they would be able to delete and add users to other groups too to which they do not belong, right?

Comment: @EpicDev The subaccounts are actually completely separate accounts to which each user must be added. If they are added to multiple accounts, they have an option under their profile tab in the top right that allows them to switch between accounts. Using this, you can actually divide your users into different accounts rather than groups if necessary and grant admin rights to the user you want administering that account. It is a little unwieldy but is better than all or nothing access. I will post a picture if my reputation allows tomorrow.

Comment: But I need groups in order to do branding, each group will have a different look.